# Is this a good use-case for Redis on a ServiceStack REST API?

Tags: redis, servicestack

I'm creating a mobile app and it requires a API service backend to get/put information for each user. I'll be developing the web service on [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/), but was wondering about the storage. I love the idea of a fast in-memory caching system like [Redis](http://redis.io/), but I have a few questions:

1. I created a sample schema of what my data store should look like. Does this seems like it's a good case for using Redis as opposed to a [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/) DB or something like that?

   [schema http://www.miles3.com/uploads/redis.png](http://www.miles3.com/uploads/redis.png)
2. How difficult is the setup for persisting the Redis store to disk or is it kind of built-in when you do writes to the store? (I'm a newbie on this NoSQL stuff)
3. I currently have my setup on [AWS](http://aws.amazon.com/) using a Linux micro instance (because it's free for a year). I know many factors go into this answer, but in general will this be enough for my web service and Redis? Since Redis is in-memory will that be enough? I guess if my mobile app skyrockets (hey, we can dream right?) then I'll start hitting the ceiling of the instance.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

#### What to think about when desigining a NoSQL Redis application

1) To develop correctly in Redis you should be thinking more about how you would structure the relationships in your C# program i.e. with the C# collection classes rather than a Relational Model meant for an RDBMS. The better mindset would be to think more about data storage like a Document database rather than RDBMS tables. Essentially everything gets blobbed in Redis via a key (index) so you just need to work out what your primary entities are (i.e. aggregate roots) 
 which would get kept in its own 'key namespace' or whether it's non-primary entity, i.e. simply metadata which should just get persisted with its parent entity.

#### Examples of Redis as a primary Data Store

Here is a good article that walks through creating a simple blogging application using Redis:

http://www.servicestack.net/docs/redis-client/designing-nosql-database

You can also look at the [source code of RedisStackOverflow](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/blob/master/src/RedisStackOverflow/RedisStackOverflow.ServiceInterface/IRepository.cs) for another real world example using Redis.

Basically you would need to store and fetch the items of each type separately.

```
var redisUsers = redis.As<User>();
var user = redisUsers.GetById(1);
var userIsWatching = redisUsers.GetRelatedEntities<Watching>(user.Id);
```

The way you store relationship between entities is making use of Redis's Sets, e.g: you can store the Users/Watchers relationship conceptually with:

```
SET["ids:User>Watcher:{UserId}"] = [{watcherId1},{watcherId2},...]
```

#### Redis is schema-less and idempotent

Storing ids into redis sets is idempotent i.e. you can add **watcherId1** to the same set multiple times and it will only ever have one occurrence of it. This is nice because it means you don't ever need to check the existence of the relationship and can freely keep adding related ids like they've never existed.

Related: writing or reading to a Redis collection (e.g. List) that does not exist is the same as writing to an empty collection, i.e. A list gets created on-the-fly when you add an item to a list whilst accessing a non-existent list will simply return 0 results. This is a friction-free and productivity win since you don't have to define your schemas up front in order to use them. Although should you need to Redis provides the [EXISTS](http://redis.io/commands/exists) operation to determine whether a key exists or a [TYPE](http://redis.io/commands/type) operation so you can determine its type.

#### Create your relationships/indexes on your writes

One thing to remember is because there are no implicit indexes in Redis, you will generally need to setup your indexes/relationships needed for reading yourself during your writes. Basically you need to think about all your query requirements up front and ensure you set up the necessary relationships at write time. The above RedisStackOverflow source code is a good example that shows this.

Note: the ServiceStack.Redis C# provider assumes you have a unique field called **Id** that is its primary key. You can configure it to use a different field with the **ModelConfig.Id()** config mapping.

#### Redis Persistance

2) Redis supports 2 types persistence modes out-of-the-box RDB and Append Only File (AOF). RDB writes routine snapshots whilst the Append Only File acts like a transaction journal recording all the changes in-between snapshots - I recommend adding both until your comfortable with what each does and what your application needs. You can read all Redis persistence at http://redis.io/topics/persistence.

Note Redis also supports trivial replication you can read more about at: http://redis.io/topics/replication

#### Redis loves RAM

3) Since Redis operates predominantly in memory the most important resource is that you have enough RAM to hold your entire dataset in memory + a buffer for when it snapshots to disk. Redis is very efficient so even a small AWS instance will be able to handle a lot of load - what you want to look for is having enough RAM.

#### Visualizing your data with the Redis Admin UI

Finally if you're using the [ServiceStack C# Redis Client](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis) I recommend installing the [Redis Admin UI](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.RedisWebServices) which provides a nice visual view of your entities. You can see a live demo of it at:
http://servicestack.net/RedisAdminUI/AjaxClient/

Comment: It definitely seems that Redis can handle my data just fine. However, one requirement I have in my app is to get a "Top 25" most watched items from the web service. In SQL this would be easy with selecting a "count(itemid)" on the watching table. Is something like this even possible with Redis or is that where it starts breaking down?

Comment: @robertmiles3 Yeah you can store items in a time ordered SortedList then select the last 25 in desc order, i.e. There's a convenient API in `T.AddToRecentsList()` and `T.GetLatestFromRecentsList()` that does this. Alternatively you can just keep a rolling list and prepend it to the start, trimming it so there's only 25 in there, see: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Redis.Tests/Examples/BlogPostExample.cs#L239

Comment: It sounds like what you are talking about would be a "Top 25 Most Recently Watched" (which I may want to do as well). However, I'd like, essentially, the top 25 "most watched" items. I.e. the appid's that have the most users watching them. So, it wouldn't be a time-ordered thing, but rather a count/volume. Does that make sense?

Comment: It's effectively the same idea, you still use a sorted set but instead of ordering by time you order by popularity, i.e. most popular tags in: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Redis.Tests/Examples/BlogPostExample.cs#L345

Comment: Nevermind, I could just use Linq for that I suppose. Something like... 
`List<int> ints = new List<int> {1,2,2,2,3,3};
var groups = ints.GroupBy(i => i);
var results = groups.OrderByDescending(g => g.Count());`