# Redis Retrieve by Foreign Key using ServiceStack.Redis

Tags: c#, database-design, nosql, redis

I am trying to get my head around the Redis/NoSQL way or designing database but I need some advice. I have the following model:

```
User {
    long UserId
    string Username 
    string Password
    List<long> ActivityIds 
}

Activity {
    long ActivityId
    long UserId
    long CourseId
    string Name
    string Description
}
```

I understand that the best way to store a list of activities associated with the user is to store a list of ids. A user can potentially have 500+ activities associated, so I don't really want to load every activity every time I load the user to display a list of them.

Is it possible in Redis and more specifically ServiceStack.Redis to select by a foreign key? For example, select all activities by UserId & CourseId at the same time? Or am I miss understanding the best way to work with Redis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using **Id** properties for primary keys on models.

Please also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8919931/85785) answer for different ways of maintaining relationships in Redis with the [ServiceStack C# client](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis).