# How does ServiceStack Redis function in retrieving data

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack

Not sure if it's the best title for the question... maybe someone could rename it for me?

My question is regarding performance of reading and combining data in c# ServiceStack wrapper for Redis and how the calls work internally.

I will explain two scenarios that will hopefully yield in a final result. One scenario has the list of category id's attached to the Transaction so that the Category can be stored independently.

**Question**: My end goal is to retrieve all transactions that have category 'food'.

I have tried to number other points where clarity would help my understanding. Consider there being 10,000 transactions and each transaction had on average 3 categories.

**Note:** There is a related question at [ServiceStack.Net Redis: Storing Related Objects vs. Related Object Ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914349/servicestack-net-redis-storing-related-objects-vs-related-object-ids?rq=1) however doesn't explain the efficiency.

**Example A**

```
public class Transaction
{
    public List<string> CategoryIds;
}
```

**Example B**

```
public class Transaction
{
    public List<string> CategoryNames;
}
```

**Code**

```
var transactionClient = redisClient.GetTypedClient<Transaction>();

//1. is this inefficient returning all transactions?
//   is there any filtering available at this part?
var allTransactions = transactionClient.GetAll();

//2. In the case of Example A where the categories are stored as id's
//   how would I map the categories to a transaction?
//   maybe I have a List that has a container with the Transaction associated with a
//   list of Categories, however this seems inefficient as I would have to loop 
//   through all transactions make a call to get their Categories and then 
//   populate the container datatype.

//3. If we are taking Example B how can I efficiently just retrieve the transactions
//   where they have a category of food.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The efficiency is **less network calls** vs **more data**. Data in Redis just gets blobbed, most of the time a single API call maps 1:1 with a redis server operation. Which means you can think about the perf implications as simply downloading a json dataset blob from a remote server's memory and deserializing it on the client - which is effectively all that happens.

In some APIs such as [GetAll()](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Redis/Generic/RedisTypedClient.cs#L388) it requires 2 calls, 1 to fetch all the ids in the Entity set, and the other to fetch all the records with those ids. The source code of the [Redis Client](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/tree/master/src/ServiceStack.Redis) is quite approachable so I recommend having a look to see exactly what's happening.

Because you've only got 3 categories, it's not that much extra data you're saving by trying to filter on the server.

So your options are basically:

- Download the entire entity dataset and filter on the client
- Maintain a custom index mapping from Category > Ids
- More Advanced: Use a server-side LUA operation to apply server side filtering (requires Redis 2.6)

Comment: Thanks, none of the filtering will be handled client side. It's all wrapped up a single WCF call e.g. GetTransactions(string categoryName) and the filtering and logic for returning a specific datatype is handled by the server. I just thought looping through all transactions and populating with category data sounded like it would bloat!

Comment: You're using WCF and you care about efficiency? You'll likely not notice any Redis optimizations :)

Comment: I've had a look at the source code and it uses the TypeSerializer to get all items back. Where would I be looking to filter the results returned initially with the LUA operation? e.g. a transaction has an accountid associated with it, i want to only retrieve those transaction with accountid 1 that is returned from the redis function (not filtered on the server-side). I've found the LUA command in AlchemyNativeClient but not sure how to use it!

Comment: It should be using the JSON Serializer now, TypeSerializer was replaced long ago. Alchemy client is for a non-standard Alchemy redis-server, so is likely not what you have. LUA APIs are here https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/Redis/IRedisClient.cs#L259 - Some info about using it is http://redis.io/commands/eval - you can use the built-in json serializer to parse the payload.