# [ServiceStack + Redis]: Get all objects from "urn:Foo:Bar"

Tags: redis, servicestack

In my Redis instance, I have a urn like

```
urn:Foo:Bar
```

Which has a lot of keys in it like:

```
urn:Foo:Bar:1
urn:Foo:Bar:2
urn:Foo:Bar:3
urn:Foo:Bar:...
urn:Foo:Bar:n
```

Each one of those simple has one property in it... but I'm not interested in that property. I'm interested in the last part of the key (the "1", "2", "3", etc) from above.

What I'd really like to be able to do is something like:

```
client.GetKeys("urn:Foo:Bar:*")
```

Or something similar, so I can get back the list of keys that match that pattern, and simply split the string to get what I really want.

Is this possible using the ServiceStack Redis C# API?

Comment: The following links may answer your question:    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583080/how-does-servicestack-redis-function-in-retrieving-data  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/servicestack/61vl9tCCBx8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use `client.SearchKeys("urn:Foo:Bar:*")`. See [here](http://redis.io/commands/keys) for documentation on available search patterns.