# ServiceStack Entities Id field name

Tags: hash, redis, servicestack

I use ServiceStack and would like to store objects as hashes in Redis and get an access to their parts (fields) by ids without serializing whole object, so I have a questions:

1. Is there a way to use other property then "Id", to mark id field? I 
   am using naming conventions, where id field is named like "class
   name+Id". So in User class there will be UserId id field, in
   Itemclass ItemId and so on.
2. Is the a way to update properties that were changed in the object
   without serializing whole object into hash and without low-level
   manipulations with hash command of Redis? For example, by using
   some sort of lambdas.

```
User user=client.GetById(userId);
user.Name="New name";
client.Update<User>(user,u=>u.Name);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can override the default using [ModelConfig](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Common/ModelConfig.cs) with:

```
ModelConfig<User>.Id(x => x.UserId);
ModelConfig<Item>.Id(x => x.ItemId);
```

This needs to be configured once on startup before you use the RedisClient.

Comment: Thank you, Demis. Haven't seen this function before. A little correct of using: ModelConfig<User>.Id(x=>x.UserId);  
And what about partial saving of object? I tried to write it by myself, but was stuck in expression trees. The issue is that if I use expression trees I have to use .Compile() method which is horrible slow down execution of saving. Also I don't want to use magic strings of property names for saving properties to hash...

Comment: If this answered your original question, mark it as answered. If you have another question you need to ask a new question. Make it obvious what the you're asking, e.g provide a code-sample if it helps describe what you're looking for.

Comment: Part N1 is answered. Part N2 is not answered. Sample of the code is provided in the part N2. What I want to do: get the User object from the redis hash, change "Name" property and save only the "Name" property into the hash without serializing and saving whole User object. I can do this by manually serializing properties into strings and using low-level hash functions, but just looking more common and obvious way like the code I provided.

Comment: The typed APIs in RedisClient blobs your objects as JSON. The Hash API's store like a string dictionary. You can partially update the hash contents with each property separately, you can't do this with the Typed APIs which blobs the object. Note: we have no plans to add partial update APIs on typed clients.

Comment: You can add custom extension methods against the `IRedisClient*` interfaces if you want to extend the clients to add this functionality.

Comment: I need partial updates too, I'm going to have a crack at implementing this.