# Storing object identifiers using Redis, key or Id?

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack

I have a master base class for (almost) all the POCO classes in my application.

```
public abstract class AceOfBase
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
}
```

Some of my main classes(`Member , Building, Community, etc.`) have a fair amount of properties so
I plan on taking advantage of the easy management [ServiceStack's](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/) [Strongly-Typed Client](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/wiki/IRedisTypedClient) provides.

[From the research I've done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914349/servicestack-net-redis-storing-related-objects-vs-related-object-ids) it seems that the client uses a structured methodology for creating keys

> Essentially POCOs gets stored into Redis as serialized JSON with both the typeof(Poco).Name and the Id used to form a unique key for that instance. E.g:
>
> urn:Poco:{Id} => '{"Id":1,"Foo":"Bar"}'

**Because at times I will be retrieving an object that inherits the base class(but which I do not know the derived class of at compile-time) how can I best go about storing the key so I can get any object easily?**

An an ideal world I would be able to configure `RedisClient` and `RedisTypedClient` to use the same naming convention for keys but I haven't found anything that lets me do this(yet) and documentation on individual methods is hard to come by for both clients.

Answer (score 1):

After digging through the ServiceStack assembly I found that the strongly-typed client's `Store()` method is actually just `SetEntry(key,value)` with a utility method for generating the key structure.

The utility method `IdUtils.CreateUrn` has a few overloads that let you specify `Type` and `Id` and then returns a string used as the key.

What I have done, then, is write a `CreateKey` method in my Repository base class which I then call when any `AceOfBase` object is created and set it to `Key`.

```
//In BaseRepository
public virtual string CreateKey<T>(T entity) where T : AceOfBase
{
 return IdUtils.CreateUrn<AceOfBase>(entity.Id);
}

//In MemberRepository
Member m = new Member(); //inherits from AceOfBase
m.Key = CreateKey(m);
```

I've implemented two sets of classes in my application as well, these help me take advantage of Redis' crazy fast query time while allowing me to use relationships normally as I would with EF.

1. **DomainModels** -- These look like normal classes in that their properties are traditionally structured.

   ```
   public class Activity : AceOfBase
   {
       public AceOfBase IndirectObject { get; set; }
       public Participant Predicate { get; set; }
       public Participant Subject { get; set; }
       public Verb Verb { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. **DataModels** -- These contain the same primitive and enums as their DomainModel counterparts but if a field is a custom type that is stored in Redis it is replaced with a string(with the same property name) representing the key for that object.

   ```
   public class Activity : AceOfBase
   {
       public string IndirectObject { get; set; }
       public string Predicate { get; set; }
       public string Subject { get; set; }
       public Verb Verb { get; set; }
   }
   ```

I have implemented `AutoMapper` with a set of custom `TypeConverter` classes that do the heavy lifting of converting `DataModel` string properties to the respective property with the same name in the `DomainModel`.   `AutoMapper` then gets called immediately before storing any object and after an object has been pulled from Redis and translates between the two model types.

```
//In Configure()
Mapper.CreateMap<string,Member>().ConvertUsing<KeyToBaseConverter<Member>>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Member, string>().ConvertUsing<BaseToKeyConverter<Member>>();

public class KeyToBaseConverter<T> : ITypeConverter<string, T> where T : AceOfBase
{
    public RedisRepository Repository { get; set; }
    public T Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return Repository.GetByKey<T>(context.SourceValue.ToString());
    }
}
public class BaseToKeyConverter<T> : ITypeConverter<T, string> where T : AceOfBase
{
    public string Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var f = context.SourceValue as AceOfBase;
        return f.Key;
    }
}
```

The only component left to address is ensuring that any `Lists` or `Sets` I create get the same formatting for their key.

Using this schema I will be able to seamlessly use the strongly-typed client alongside the string-client, ensuring that even when pulling objects without the strongly-typed client I can determine and safely cast the JSON blob into the correct Type by examining only the Key property.