# AddItemToSet vs StoreRelatedEntities

Tags: servicestack.redis

I am trying to understand when someone would use AddItemToSet vs StoreRelatedEntities.

It seems the former is a way to associate a set label with a string-based item handle.

The latter is a way to associate two entities, which seems like a more generalized operation.

What is it that AddItemToSet does that StoreRelatedEntities can't do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AddItemToSet` API in [ServiceStack.Redis](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis) is a **1:1** mapping that calls Redis' Server [SADD Operation](http://redis.io/commands/sadd), i.e. adds an item to a Redis SET.

The `StoreRelatedEntities` is a higher-level operation that also maintains an index containing relationship between the entities described in detail in this [Storing Related Entities in Redis answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8919931/85785).