# ElasticSearch NEST alternative for C# .Contains()

Tags: contains, nest, elasticsearch-net

Having moved from [Redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27023692/servicestack-redis-search-is-very-slow-how-to-optimize/) to ElasticSearch for my personal project, I need some help from the masters. The basic requirement is as below:

1. Indexes contain POCO of type Album which has fields such as Artist, Title, Year
2. When user enters a search-term, for ex "2", I should get the Albums in which the above fields contain the search-term
3. It should match Album Title like "2 States", Artists such as "2 Pac" and Year in "2014,1992..etc"

I have got the code working just as expected, but I'm using wildchars which I believe will impact the performance. The code is below:

```
var results = Client.Search<Album>(body =>
    body.Query(query =>
        query.QueryString(qs =>
            qs.OnFieldsWithBoost(d => d
                .Add(f => f.AlbumName.ToLowerInvariant(), 5.0)
                .Add(f => f.AlbumTitle.ToLowerInvariant(), 2.0)
                )
                .Query(String.Format("{0}*", searchText))
            )
        )
        .Take(100)
    );
```

Any suggestions to improve the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an index using the Ngram tokenizer. And then use the search string without wildcard.

Example: [How to search for a part of a word with ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467067/how-to-search-for-a-part-of-a-word-with-elasticsearch)

Ngram tokenizer: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html