# Redis key partitioning practices with linked items

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack

I'm using a Redis database and ServiceStack client for it. I have a class called "Post" which has a property GroupId. Now when I'm storing this class the key is "urn:post:2:groupid:123". Now if I want to find all posts related to one group i need to use SearchKeys("urn:*groupid:123") method to retrieve all posts related to one group. Is this best practice to use Redis DB or should I convert my post key into form of "urn:groupid:123"post:2" ? If so how I can achieve this?

Post class:

```
  public class Post
    {
        public const string POST_INCREMENT_KEY =  "POST_INCREMENT";

        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public string GroupId { get; set; }

        public void BuildId(long uniqueId)
        {
            Id = uniqueId  + ":groupid:" + GroupId;
        }
    }
```

Code for storing post:

```
var post = new Post
                {
                    GroupId = groupId,
                    Message = Request.Form["message"]
                };

                post.BuildId(_client.Increment(Post.POST_INCREMENT_KEY, 1));
                _client.Store(post);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice in redis is to [maintain an index of the relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8919931/85785) you want to query.

### Manually maintaining an index in Redis

An index is just a redis `SET` containing the related Ids you want to maintain, given that you want to "retrieve all posts related to one group" I would maintain the following index:

```
const string GroupPostIndex = "idx:group>post:{0}";
```

So that everytime you store a post, you also want to update the index, e.g:

```
client.Store(post);
client.AddItemToSet(GroupPostIndex.Fmt(groupId), post.Id);
```

Note: Redis SET operations are idempotent in that adding an item/id multiple times to a SET will always result in there being only one occurrence of that item in the SET, so its always safe to add an item to the set whenever storing a POST without needing to check if it already exists.

Now when I want to retrieve all posts in a group I just need to get all the ids from the SET with:

```
var postIds = client.GetAllItemsFromSet(GroupPostIndex.Fmt(groupId));
```

Then fetch all the posts with those ids:

```
var posts = redis.As<Post>().GetByIds(postIds);
```

### Using ServiceStack.Redis Related Entities API's

The above shows what's required to maintain an index in Redis yourself, but as this is a common use-case, [ServiceStack.Redis](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis) also offers a high-level typed API that you can use instead.

Which lets you store related entities with:

```
client.As<Group>().StoreRelatedEntities(groupId, post);
```

> Note: this also takes care of storing the Post

and retrieve them with:

```
var posts = client.As<Group>().GetRelatedEntities<Post>(groupId);
```

It also offers other convenience API's like quickly finding out how many posts there are within a given group:

```
var postsCount = client.As<Group>().GetRelatedEntitiesCount<Post>(groupId);
```

and deleting either 1 or all entities in the group:

```
client.As<Group>().DeleteRelatedEntity<Post>(groupId, postId);
client.As<Group>().DeleteRelatedEntities<Post>(groupId); //all group posts
```

Comment: Welll thats just awesomeness

Comment: Interesting... I got a nullrefence exception from StoreRelatedEntities method when i had a property called Id in my Post and its type was string. Fixed it by changing type to ulong

Comment: @Mino hmmm, I haven't been able to repro this with String Ids [in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/commit/7bbc3fdce7557ee099212cfb9916885b763b581f). Can you add a [gist](https://gist.github.com/) that shows a repro?

Comment: Actually it happen because Id was null (I didn't set any value into it).

Comment: Btw. is there an easy way to fetch related entities in specified order?

Comment: @Mino Not by default as redis `SET` is an unordered collection, you would need to add an order on the model and order it on the client.