# Retrieve selection of servicestack redis session objects based on values of properties

Tags: redis, servicestack, stackexchange.redis, servicestack.redis, servicestack-auth

I want to update multiple servicestack user sessions that are stored in redis. I want to return all sessions that have a custom property set to a certain value, then I can process them. At the moment the best solution I have returns all keys as such:

```
List<string> sessionkeys = redis.SearchKeys("urn:iauthsession:*");
```

I am thinking this will not scale well. I'd like to do something analogous to:

```
List<string> sessionkeys = redis.AllKeys.Where(x=>x.ParentId == 3);
```

Is this possible with redis, and if so how, ideally using standard libraries with ServiceStack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `SearchKeys` you want to be using the newer [Redis Scan API's](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#new-scan-apis-added) which let you iterate over keys in a cursor.

Redis values are blobbed and not indexed so there's not much opportunity to optimize this. The most efficient way would be to inspect the values using a custom [server-side LUA operation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#new-iredisclient-lua-apis) which will minimize the number of requests and payload sent to the client.

Redis embedded version of LUA has cjson which can be used for deserializing JSON values, the [Lua guide for Redis users](http://www.redisgreen.net/blog/intro-to-lua-for-redis-programmers/) has some examples of using this.

Since Redis doesn't support server-side querying or indexes, the Redis way would be to premept the queries you need to query on and maintain custom indexes whenever a Session is saved, some info on how to maintain custom indexes in Redis are at:

- [Storing Related Entities and Maintaining Custom Indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8919931/85785)
- [Designing a NoSQL Database using Redis](http://docs.servicestack.net/redis-client/designing-nosql-database)

In ServiceStack you can override `OnSaveSession()` in your AppHost which gets called whenever a Session is saved.

Comment: answered my question perfectly. and my next question too!