# Is there a speed different between servicestack.redis GetAll().where() and GetByIds()

Tags: c#, .net, redis, servicestack

I was using servicestack.redis recently, and I need query from `IRedisTypedClient`. I know all data is in memory, but still want to know, is there a speed different between `GetAll().Where()` and `GetByIds()`?

`GetAll()` and `GetByIds()` are two methods provided by servicestack.redis.

Use `GetAll()` can continue search in result(by lambda), that means I can use some custom conditions, but I don't know, whether that will load all data from redis memory then search in `IEnumable<T>`, and whether the search speed will slower than `GetByIds()`.

Comment: Best answer is to try it and find out...

Comment: @BugFinder you are right, i'll try it tonight, when i find out tell your guys.

Answer (score 2):

I just did a experiment, I stored 1 million object(ps:there is a servicestack's bug, can only store about half million object once).

queried with these two methods.

```
DateTime beginDate = DateTime.Now;
Debug.WriteLine("查询1开始");`  
Website site = WebsiteRedis.GetByCondition(w => w.Name == "网址2336677").First();
double time = (DateTime.Now - beginDate).TotalMilliseconds;
Debug.WriteLine("耗时：" + time + "ms");

DateTime beginDate2 = DateTime.Now;
Debug.WriteLine("查询2开始");
Website site2 = WebsiteRedis.GetByID(new Guid("29284415-5de0-4781-bea4-5e01332814b2"));
double time2 = (DateTime.Now - beginDate2).TotalMilliseconds;
Debug.WriteLine("耗时：" + time2 + "ms");
```

Result is 

 `GetAll().Where()` - takes 19 seconds, 
 `GetById()`- take 190ms.

I guess it's because `servicestack` use object id as `redis` key, so never use `GetAll().Where()` as query, every object should related with id and use `GetById()` as query. `GetAll()` should use on object with less records.

Comment: Please don't use screen shots of code. Paste the code in

Comment: I edit it now, still have some problem with markdown code, but ok to see.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at the implementations of [GetAll and GetByIds](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/0cdbd208ee6a66b1287cec930b4021218821a757/src/ServiceStack.Redis/Generic/RedisTypedClient.cs#L411-L427) to see how they work.

GetByIds just converts all Ids to a fully qualified Key which each entry is stored under then calls [GetValues()](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/0cdbd208ee6a66b1287cec930b4021218821a757/src/ServiceStack.Redis/Generic/RedisTypedClient.cs#L374) which creates a single MGET request to fetch all the values:

```
public IList<T> GetByIds(IEnumerable ids)
{
    if (ids != null)
    {
        var urnKeys = ids.Map(x => client.UrnKey<T>(x));
        if (urnKeys.Count != 0)
            return GetValues(urnKeys);
    }

    return new List<T>();
}

public IList<T> GetAll()
{
    var allKeys = client.GetAllItemsFromSet(this.TypeIdsSetKey);
    return this.GetByIds(allKeys.ToArray());
}
```

GetAll fetches all the Ids from the `TypeIdsSetKey` (i.e. Redis SET containing all ids for that Type) then calls `GetByIds()`.

So GetByIds is faster because it makes one less call to Redis, but together they only make 2 Redis operations.

Note they both return an in memory .NET `List<T>` so you can use LINQ to further filter the returned results, but it returns **all results for that Type** and the filtering is performed on the client so this isn't efficient for large datasets. Instead you should look at [creating manual indexes using Redis SETs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8919931/85785) for common queries.

Comment: awesome, i just reading the question you linked in answer, and checking your profile, turn out you answer me at the same time.