# What does IRedisClient.As<T>() do behind the scenes?

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack.redis

I'm curently using the c# ServiceStack RedisClient in the following way

```
   using (var cache = new BasicRedisClientManager(readWriteHosts).ClientFactory.GetClient())
   {
        var r = cache.As<Foo>();
        var myItem = r.GetById(123);
   }
```

I want to know what happens behind the scenes with this? How does Redis know which type relates to which key? It can't be inspecting each type for a match, that would be too slow. When I set the object, I'm serialising it myself and adding it as string - so it can't know from there either.

It works fantastically, I even tried changing properties and namespaces of the type to see what happens and it just handles it. Does anyone know **How**?

Comment: Well, see for yourself - https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/2b833b6e574067bc94dd5a504cf2fd5d6e7ce12c/src/ServiceStack.Redis/RedisClient.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt you can just [read the source code](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/3a9b7db6e6e33ea52917b65d0bc41a2bbd993f94/src/ServiceStack.Redis/RedisClient.cs#L398), i.e. it's effectively just returning a Typed Generic RedisClient:

```
public IRedisTypedClient<T> As<T>()
{
    return new RedisTypedClient<T>(this);
}
```

Whilst the source code for [RedisTypedClient](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Redis/Generic/RedisTypedClient.cs) shows exactly what it does, [this existing answer explains roughly how it works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8919931/85785).