# Redis ids:xyz is a set of all keys in urn:xyz - no grooming

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack

We are experience that for every key we are storing in redis urn:xyz a entry in a set ids:xyz is created automatically. see following printscreen

[image]

while our keys have an expiration date of 5 days, the entries in the set seem to be stored forever - and our webapplication gets slower and slower.

Can we prevent Redis of writing these indexes? Or is there a simple way to set a expiration date for these entries?

Note: we are using Redis in combination of c# and ServiceStack.Redis for accessing the data.

Answer (score 1):

These indexes are added when you use ServiceStack.Redis [high-level generic typed clients](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8919931/85785). If you used the same typed client to remove the `Delete*()` the entries these indexes will be automatically removed, but using an expiry only applies to the data not the indexes which is maintained in a SET for each Type so each individual index entry can't have an expiry that matches the payload.

If you're going to be expiring keys I'd suggest avoiding the high-level `IRedisTypedClient<T>` client and use the string-based `IRedisClient` APIs instead.